# image alignment in matlab

Tags: image, image-processing, alignment, matlab

I'm trying to align several images in matlab and I'm having trouble getting matlab to align them properly. I want to align them so that I can overlay them to make a larger image by stitching/averaging them together. I posted several of the images [here](http://imageshack.us/g/1/9903605/). While it is not difficult to align 5 images manually I want to make a script to do it so that I do not need to align hundreds of similar images manually as well.

Over the past few days I've tried several ways of getting this to work. My thought was that if I could filter the images enough then I could make a mask for the letters and then it would be easy to align them--but I haven't been able to make it work.

I've tried using local adaptive thresholding to compensate for a nonuniform brightness level across the picture but it hasn't allowed me to align them properly. For the actual image alignment I've been using imregister() and normxcorr2() but both do not properly align the images.

I don't think that this should be that difficult to do but I haven't been able to do it. Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: uploaded images after performing various operations [here](http://imageshack.us/g/1/9905169/)

Comment: It's called image registration.

Comment: The difficulty is that your images are extremely low contrast. You may want to try to apply an edge filter first, and use the positions of the edges to get better alignment

Comment: Have you tried to use correlation?

Comment: I've tried using edges but I haven't found good parameters to generate decent edges. I wrote a script to find the black dots that are in every image and remove them by replacing them with the median of the surrounding points and that seems to help. I think it would be better if I could do this without using local adaptive thresholding but that's just my gut feeling. I'll upload some of the images I've generated to the imageshack.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some feature detection, followed by the RANSAC algorithm to find the transformation between any pair of images.

see this demo on the Mathworks web-site: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/feature-detection-extraction-and-matching-with-ransac-73589.html